# Acer Aspire 3 laptop randomly turns off monitor and goes to sleep

Tags: laptop, sleep, power, lid

For a long time my Acer Aspire 3 laptop running Windows 10 randomly switches off the screen or goes to sleep.  It seems to happen mostly when I'm typing.

Looking in the Event Viewer I would see a Kernel-Power event saying reason for Sleep was "Button or Lid".

At first I thought that I was accidentally pressing the power button (as it is on the F1 key that does not need the Fn key to be held down) but changing the setting to require Fn to be pressed did not help.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that there is a magnet in the lid that is used to detect when the lid is closed.

The sensor for this magnet is right in the place where I put my wrist on which there is often a watch which has a magnetic strap on it.  This magnet was confusing the laptop into thinking that the lid was being closed.

I can either disable the lid detector (e.g. [prevent monitor switching when closing laptop lid](https://superuser.com/questions/88548/prevent-monitor-switching-when-closing-laptop-lid)) or stop wearing my watch when typing!

This took me a long time to solve and I could not find any similar answer so I thought I'd post this in case it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Hey this is completely random and I was having this same issue as well and couldnt get anything else online to help. Until I found this thread and realized that a few days ago my friend gave me a bracelet with a magnetic clasp that I've been wearing and drags across the keyboard in the same way. Took it off and it hasn't happened again. Thanks so much for saving me a trip to a repair shop!

Comment: Please see [https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer). Answers are for providing answers to questions. "Me too" and "Thanks" -answers [will get deleted](https://superuser.com/help/deleted-answers) as they provide no useful info. Please note that low quality answers will eventually lead  to [answering ban](https://superuser.com/help/answer-bans).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1081745)